# How to use Reader and Writer monads in Scala?

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, monads

Suppose I am writing a program, which reads some input, processes it and writes the output.

Suppose also I have a function `def process(input: MyInput): MyOutput`

Now I should use a `Reader` monad for the input.

```
def readAndProcess(reader: MyReader[MyInput]): MyReader[MyOutput] = 
  for(in <- reader) yield process(in)
```

So far, so good but now I need to write the output somewhere. That is, I need a `Writer` monad and can define a function `readProcessAndWrite`

```
def readProcessAndWrite(reader: MyReader[MyInput]): MyWriter[MyOutput]
```

Suppose I have a function

```
def write(out: MyOutput, writer: MyWriter[MyOutput]) : MyWriter[MyOutput]
```

How can I define `readProcessAndWrite` ?

```
def readProcessAndWrite(reader: MyReader[MyInput], 
                        writer: MyWriter[MyOutput]): MyWriter[MyOutput] = ... ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand a bit. Reader monad isn't intended for reading input to the program, but to avoid passing the same argument to various functions. Similarly, Writer is about accumulating some state over calculations, not about writing it to (e.g.) standard output or a file. (Of course, you can write it after it's accumulated, but you wouldn't use the Writer monad for this!)

If you really want to combine them, you need either to write a combined monad (`ReaderWriter[MyInput, MyOutput]`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909649/what-is-the-rws-monad-and-when-is-it-used)) or [monad transformers](http://debasishg.blogspot.ru/2011/07/monad-transformers-in-scala.html) (`ReaderT[MyInput, Writer[MyOutput]]` or vice versa).

Comment: Thank you. I will update my question. Now I wonder how to write combined monad and transformer you mentioned. Could you give an example ?

Comment: I've added a couple of links which may be helpful.