# Understanding the RWST in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have looked at [this](https://mmhaskell.com/blog/2017/3/6/making-sense-of-multiple-monads) to try to understand how several transformer monads interact, and especially getting a better understanding of `lift` and *stacking* with monads.

For the RWST monad found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Lazy.html) (I think this is the best documentation of it), is it the case that it is a stacked monad where the Reader, Writer, State each are a monadic layer (and in that order of stacking).  Or how is it supposed to be understood?
When I look at the definition `runRWST :: r -> s -> m (a, s, w)` I understand it as taking reader-environment a state-environment and wrapping any monad `m` around the return value of `RWS`. This also means that there only exists two layers of monads in this monad. That is, the outer monad `m` , and a tuple containing several monads.

This in turn also means that you can only use the `lift` once. Lifting a value from either the *reader* or the *state* monad into the outer monad.

In that sense `get` and `ask` are just two functions applying one of either two of the inner monads. For this last point I am still not sure I understand why you would need both a *reader* a *state*-monad even having read [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909649/what-is-the-rws-monad-and-when-is-it-used). The *reader* is only meaningfull for read-only I guess, but if one didn't want that, could one use a transformer monad around two seperat *state*-monads?

##### An example:

The comments have given me reason to ponder and make the following more explicit.... Of the following type definition what what would be the inner monad, and the outer monad? Is the `RWST` itself a Monad wrapped around (and therefor an outer monad) `Either String` (the inner monad) ?

```
type MyRWST a = RWST
                 (String -> Either String MyType)       
                 [Int] 
                 (MyEnv, [String], [String])
                 (Either String)
                 a
```

Comment: It is _equivalent_ to a stack of `ReaderT`, `WriterT` and `StateT`. Whether you look at it as a single transformer or all three or just two is a matter of interpretation, but at any rate the type system treats it as a single transformer, therefore you'd only use `lift` once - but this does _not_ lift values from either reader or state or writer into the RWST monad, but from the underlying monad (e.g. `IO`). - - I'm struggling to understand what actually your question is...

Comment: RWST is _not_ a monad stack, it is a single monad that implements multiple functionalities (reader, writer, state).

Comment: @leftaroundabout what do you mean by "_but from the underlying monad_" is that the `a` in the `runRWST :: r -> s -> m (a, s, w)`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner are you then disagreeing with leftaroundabout ?

Comment: @Piskator no, it's `m`

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have tried to elaborate my confusion, if you could point to it based on this new example.

Comment: no, we typed in parallel I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inner monad of a monad *transformer* is always a type parameter. The type you've provided isn't a transformer.

```
type MyRWST a = RWST
                 (String -> Either String MyType)       
                 [Int] 
                 (MyEnv, [String], [String])
                 (Either String)
                 a
```

This is a `Monad`. Compare this to a transformer like [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t:MaybeT).

> ```
> newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
> ```

`MaybeT` takes two type parameters, and the first itself takes a parameter, so its kind is `(* -> *) -> * -> *`. With more explicit parentheses, that's `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`. And now we can see why it's called a *transformer*. It takes one monad (of kind `* -> *`) and *transforms* it into a new monad (also of kind `* -> *`).

[`RWST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-CPS.html#t:RWST) is defined as

> ```
> newtype RWST r w s m a = RWST { unRWST :: r -> s -> w -> m (a, s, w) }
> ```

Now this takes a *lot* of type arguments, but if we fix `r`, `w`, and `s`, we get a transformer. That is, `RWST` is not, itself, a monad transformer, but for any `r`, `w`, and `s`, `RWST r w s` *is* a transformer. The full kind of `RWST` is

```
RWST :: * -> * -> * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

And while you can *think* of `RWST` as having three layers (reader, writer, and state), it really only does have one. The "next layer down" of `RWST r w s m` is really `m`. So to directly answer your question about `lift`, the type signature of `lift` is

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

and when `t ~ RWST r w s`, we get

```
lift :: Monad m => m a -> RWST r w s m a
```

So a single `lift` takes us over the *whole* `RWST r w s` mess.

Comment: @leftaroundabout and Silvio Mayolo ,yes  the one I originally stated does compile the way it was written.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah, thank you! I was reading the `MyRWST` declaration as a `data` not a `type`, so I thought OP's `RWST` was a data constructor of their own defining. I see the issue now. Edited the post.